# Are there smaller chain rings available for Shimano Tiagra Triple?

Tags: shimano, crankset, compatibility, touring-bikes

I have a Shimano Tiagra Triple 30/39/50 and I want to find out what is compatible in terms of smaller chainrings for touring. Ideally, I’d like to be able to go down to a 26 or even a 24 for the smallest. Thinking in term of 26/36/46 or 48. This is a 4 bolt crank and it seems there’s little to no compatibility with other sets.

Comment: It's a bit more expensive, but since it's a wear item anyway, have you thought about getting a freewheel with a larger range?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the asymmetric four bolt pattern that Shimano switched to for these cranks is a new patttern and so far there are no small inner rings available. The best advice I can give is to switch to the older five bolt style crank, for which many small rings are available. I use 26-39-50 on the previous generation of Tiagra with no trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what BCD is used for the smallest ring?   4 bolt holes could be 65mm or some other size.

https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0230/9291/files/Measure_BCD_5ad6ccfa-f146-4048-ac0f-e2279602c9e1.pdf   is one way to measure it

Assuming your crankset is a FC-4703 then the specs are at
https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/tiagra-4700/FC-4703.html  and suggest its 74mm BCD.

Sheldon says that a 74mm BCD will take a 24 tooth chainring, or 26 and 28 options as well.  He also suggests a "deflector" to help the chain make the big jump down from the 39 without missing, to prevent damage to the frame.